# How to read sealed class subclass in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

In my Android studio project, I have a construct like following:

```
@Stable
interface Levels {

    @Immutable
    sealed class LevelData {

        object Empty : LevelData()

        @Immutable
        data class L1(
            val locationData: Locations.LocationData.StageL1
        ) : LevelData()
    }
}
```

In another class I have `val levelData = mutableStateOf<Levels.LevelData>(Levels.LevelData.Empty)` variable with Empty as its default. Then the state changes and I would like to access the `locationData` in `levelData` like `levelData.value.locationData`?

Autocomplete in Android Studio does not show me any `locationData` member access in the drop down?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `levelData` variable holds mutable state of super type `Levels.LevelData`. You need to cast the object to L1 to access `locationData`

```
val value = levelData.value
if(value is Levels.LevelData.L1){
    val locationData = value.locationData
    //perform action on locationData
}
```